# Adding token in the views header and footer

Tags: webforms

I have created webform and displaying the webform submission data using views. In above the submission data, I mean in the header, I want to display the data from the webform body field. I tried using adding the "Global: Unfiltered text" and placing the token of the body field. But when I view the page, it is not showing the body content instead of showing the token itself.

Please tell me how to use token of the webform body field in the header without using "Global: PHP"?

Comment: Did you check the box "Use tokens from the first row"?

Comment: Yes I did but it just showing me the token itself instead of replacement

Answer (score 1):

The "Use replacement tokens from the first row" checkbox is essential. It works with either the "Global: Text Area" option or "Global: Unfiltered text." Here is a screenshot of both working:

[image: Full Views UI]
[image]

Comment: I have given like that only but its not working.

Comment: Token replacement happening only there is some content. If there is no content, then token replacement is not working...Please suggest me if anything i need to add to get this replacement to work.